# Foreign keys are maybe not correctly mapped so I get an error in the REST API of creation of data in database

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, foreign-keys

I have two tables :

```
societe (
   id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
   ...,
   fk_adresse int NOT NULL
);
```

(fk_adresse is a foreign key)

The other table is

```
bureau (
    fk_societe INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    ...,
    fk_convention INT NOT NULL,
    ....
 );
```

fk_societe is both the primary key of the "bureau" table and a foreign key towards the "societe" table and fk_convention is a foreign key

My Java mapping for bureau is :

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "fk_societe", nullable = false)
private Integer fkSociete;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumns({ @JoinColumn(name = "fk_societe", referencedColumnName = "id") })
private Societe societe;

....

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "fk_convention", referencedColumnName = "id")
private Convention convention;

....
```

My controller is

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;application/json")
public void createBureau(Bureau bureau){
    bureauRepository.save(bureau);
}

@GetMapping("/bureaux")
public List<Bureau> getAllBureaux() {
    return bureauRepository.findAll();
}

//recherche de bureau
@GetMapping("/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<Bureau> getBureauById(@PathVariable(value = "id") Integer id)
    throws ResourceNotFoundException {
        
    Bureau bureau = bureauRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Bureau not found");
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(bureau);                                                        
}
```

The search of one bureau and the list of all the bureau work fine but the creation of one bureau does not work. In my societe table I have a societe with the id 42 so I send a create (POST) request with Postman and with the following data :

```
fk_societe          42  
fk_devise            1
fk_langue           67
fk_convention        2
est_4_e_directive   true
est_transitoire     false
```

Postman says to me that there is a 500 error and in my console I have the following error

```
2020-10-16 11:50:07.115 ERROR 8368 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERREUR: une valeur NULL viole la contrainte NOT NULL de la colonne ½ fk_societe ╗ dans la relation ½ bureau ╗
DÚtailá: La ligne en Úchec contient (null, 0, 0, null, f, f).
```

which is translated by

```
ERROR: a NULL value violates the NOT NULL constraint of the fk_societe column in the bureau relationship
Details : the failing line contains (null, 0, 0, null, f, f).
```

Maybe my foreign keys are not correctly mapped...

Answer (score 0):

Try to correct your mapping for the bureau in the following way:

```java
@Id
@Column(name = "fk_societe", nullable = false)
private Integer fkSociete;

@MapsId
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "fk_societe")
private Societe societe;
```

As you use the same column `fk_societe` as the entity id and the foreign key to the other entity, you should use the `@MapsId` [annotation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-derived) here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I get a new error : nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property [com.gpsa.refontebcf.entities.Bureau.societe]; nested exception is org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property [com.gpsa.refontebcf.entities.Bureau.societe]] with root cause. It looks like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11104897/hibernate-attempted-to-assign-id-from-null-one-to-one-property-employee

Comment: I've just realized that the bureau argument is always null when I consume the REST API of bureau creation

Comment: My mapping assume that the `societe` should not be `null` and the id of the `Societe` entity is auto generated or not null.

Comment: Yes, of course. But for a reason I am missing the fk_societe and the fk_convention mapped from the JSON request message are null...